# Django Timesince does not show correct value

Tags: python, html, django, web

I want to display "timesince" value for a date in my application. The date is correct but the timesince value is wrong.

Received Date and Timesince equivalent, screenshot was taken at August 10, 4:39PM

[![image][1]][1]

The first item should show 30 minutes since time is 4:09PM.

Here's my HTML code:

```html
<tr>
    <td>{{ trip.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ trip.date_depart }}</td>
    <td>{{ trip.equipment }}</td>
    {% for k,v in materials.items %}
    {% if k == trip.material %}
    <td>{{ v }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <td>{{ trip.farm }}</td>
    <td>{{ trip.destination }}</td>
    <td>{{ trip.load }}</td>
    <td>{{ trip.date_arrive }}</td>
    <td>{{ trip.date_arrive | timesince }}</td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE:**

By default, my settings in settings.py are:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

When i tried saving a date (e.g. Aug. 11, 2022, 3:35 p.m.) using `datetime.now()` it will be saved as `"2022-08-11 23:35:38.073899+08"` in the Postgres database. Is Postgres taking my date as UTC and converting it to my local timezone when saving? And vice versa when i try to retrieve it?

**UPDATE 2**

Temporary solution i could think of is to set the timezone to 'Asia/Manila' while project is not yet scaled to include other timezone functionalities.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH46q.jpg

Comment: Do you have timezones configured for your project? And are all of your `datetime`s TZ aware? The `datetime`s which have `timesince` look like they might to be a few hours out given the timestamp of the screenshot.

Comment: I am using UTC timezone for my project. I have another project with the same settings but the `timesince` value displayed is correct. I compared both settings.py file but see no difference.